# Where in Setup, or in Permission Sets, is the "Configure Messaging" permission set?

Tags: servicecloud

Help pages about setting up text messaging (SMS or Facebook Messenger) channels in Service Cloud contain this procedure:
Quick Find "Messaging", and select "Messaging Settings" . 
For instance https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=livemessage_enable.htm&type=5 . 
But doing so yields no hits. Our org is on LE and is Unlimited Edition, so what's the secret to getting started configuring messaging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000eGywQAE

https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/datasheets/digital-engagement-datasheet.pdf

[image]

Have you paid for it? It used to be called "Live Message" in Classic, but now fits under the "Digital Engagement" product for Lightning. Since you don't see "messaging" in your setup, I'd assume you thought it wasn't an add-on. You'll have to talk with your account executive.

Comment: TY. Yes, I tried to do that, but at step 8 , there was no Messaging presence status on the list, so i couldn't do it.  I can create some arbitrary Presence Status items, but I doubt that it is the right workaround.

Comment: Also, I see that at step 11, there is no "Messaging Sessions" object available on the list. Object Manager also does not see a Messaging Sessions object.

Comment: Finally I see that I must "set up Omni-Channel for Messaging" first - but where are instructions for that? Google just finds the same help page.

Comment: and the page above in Help is https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=live_message_setup_flow.htm&type=0 which says "This flow is available from the Messaging setup page in Lightning Experience." But Quick find does not find that page.

Comment: it continues : 
"You can also start the flow from Service Setup in Lightning Experience.  ... In Service Setup, you can find recommended setup flows, content, and tips based on what you’ve set up already. If you don’t see the setup flow you’re looking for, you can click View All to see the full list." I clicked View All and no tile seems to be about Messaging.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this as I don't have it set up, just had seen the documentation. Let me play around with it.

Comment: Edited the answer. It doesn't appear to be out-of-the-box features with service console - it's an add-on.

Comment: That must be it! lol   time to write a Chat Lightning web component ...